# Complex exponential and lines

Tags: complex-analysis

**Notation**

$$\operatorname{exp}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{exp}(z):=e^z.$$

> a) Show that $\operatorname{exp}$ maps vertical lines to circles with the origin as center.
>
> b) Show that $\operatorname{exp}$ maps horizontal lines to half rays from the origin to infinity.

Of course, the first logical step would be to say that vertical lines are given by $z=a+i\cdot 0$ and horizontal ones by $z=0+bi$. Now, I'm not sure how to show that $e^z=e^a$ represent circles and $e^z = e^{ib} = \cos b + i\sin b$ half rays.

How do I best approach this?

Comment: Why shouldn't $\{t+13i\,:\, t\in\Bbb R\}$ be a vertical line, in your opinion?

Comment: It is *horizontal* ;))) (confusion in the question too)

Comment: @Gae.S. I was just thinking over vertical lines as lines having only a real part, and horizontal lines - only an imaginary part. How would you define them?

Comment: $\Bbb C$ is naturally a cartesian plane. Lines in that plane.

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, thank you. It should have been $\{13+ti\,:\, t\in\Bbb R\}$ for it to be vertical.

Comment: @Zachary As best I can tell, you saw someone say $\Re(z) = a$ is the general form for a vertical line (which is true) and thought this meant that $z$ is a real number (which is false).  In fact, the set $\{z : \Re(z) = a\}$ is equal to $\{a + i t : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ so your lines should all have an unrestricted real parameter $t$

Comment: Ok, so say $z=c+it, t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a vertical line. Then, $e^z = e^c e^{it}$. Then $e^c$ can be seen as the radius of a circle, and since $t\in\mathbb{R}$ all points on the circle with center in the origin and radius $e^c$ will be reached.

Answer (score 1):

A *vertical line* in $\Bbb C$ is parallel to the $y$-axis; thus it is a set of points of the form

$a + it, \; a \in \Bbb R \; \text{fixed}, \; t \in \Bbb R,  -\infty \to t \to \infty; \tag 1$

we have

$e^{a + it} = e^a e^{it} = e^a(\cos t + i \sin t), \tag 2$

which traces out a circle in $\Bbb C$ of radius $e^a$ as $-\infty \to t \to \infty$.

A *horizontal line* in $\Bbb C$ is parallel to the $x$-axis; thus *it* is a set of points of the form

$t + ib, \; b \in \Bbb R \; \text{fixed}, \; t \in \Bbb R, -\infty \to t \to \infty, \tag 3$

and thus,

$e^{t + ib} = e^t e^{ib} = e^t(\cos b + i\sin b); \tag 4$

this traces out the half-ray of points of the form (in polar corrdinates) $re^{i \theta}$, where $0 < r < \infty$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ is that unique angle such that

$\cos \theta = \cos b, \; \sin \theta = \sin b. \tag 5$

We note in closing that $a + 0i$ is a point on the real axis $\Bbb R$, not a line, and that $0 + bi$ is a point on the imaginary axis $i\Bbb R$, and that neither represents a line in $\Bbb C$.